# Address autocompletion doesn't work after compiling `elc` files for `mu4e`

Tags: mu4e, auto-complete-mode, compilation

After compiling `elc` files for `mu4e` in `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu4e` (Ubuntu 20.04) with

```
sudo emacs -Q -batch -L . -f batch-native-compile *.el
```

I get this error when writing an address of the `To:` field

```
Company: backend company-capf error "Symbol’s function definition is void: start" with args (prefix)
```

Prior to `elc` compiling `mu4e` everything worked alright. So I guess some bits of the config are out of sync now. Grateful for any tips.

(Note that in `mu4e` address auto-completion is enabled by default, i.e., `mu4e-compose-complete-addresses` is set to true)

I'm using mu4e 1.5.11 on Emacs 28.0.50 with native compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved when I build Emacs from the branch mentioned here:

https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm/issues/835#issuecomment-841524743